# Stop Android from creating folders on a media player external USB drive

Tags: external-sd, file-management, folders

I have an X96 media player running Android 11. Whenever I attach an external USB drive or SD card, Android will create a bunch of directories, an "Android" one (this I know about), but also "Movies", "Music", and "Photo" folders.

Is there any way of stopping this from happening? This is not a phone card but a media player, and the extra folders are completely unnecessary...

In the meantime, I'm using CX File Manager and deleting them, but they're created automatically every time I reboot.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Looks like this is a possible duplicate of [Is there a way to stop Android from creating folders on the SD card such as "Android" and "Download"?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/200463/44325). Please check the answer there and let us know.